# VueJS search filter error: cannot ready 'search' of undefined

Tags: json, vue.js, search, filter, axios

I'm building an app to consume a json and list it with a search filter input and other stuff.

I've already tried to create the function but it didn't work.

Codesandbox URL
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-7iev3?fontsize=14

```
    search: "",
```

Its showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined" but its defined

Answer (score 1):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined" doesn't mean that "search" is undefined but the parent object is. In your case, "this.search", this is undefined in your callback. You should use "self.search" because you already defined it or just change your syntax into:

```
computed: {
    produtoFiltrado: function() {
      return this.produtos.filter((cust) => {
        return cust.nome.match(this.search);
      });
    }
  }
```

Arrow functions doens't bind their "this" to their context so you can access your vue methods, props, data etc. using this without any problems

Comment: Castellini, thanks. Now I have another problem... The items arent shown. If I change the condition v-for="produtos in produtoFiltrado" for v-for"produtos in gc.produtos" it works but not filtered as I wish

Comment: change this.produtos with this.gc.produtos in your computed property, you area iterating the wrong array

Comment: Castellini, now I have "TypeError: this.gc.produtos is undefined"

Comment: It's undefined until you get your ajax response. You can either default gc in data as {produtos: []} because i guess you always need a produtos list or just check if produtos is defined in your computed before iterating it and otherwise return an empty array

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific because I'm new in Vue.. I'd be grateful if you help me with my code, Davide

Comment: In your data you default your attributes that you want to use in your component right? You defined "gc" as an empty object and then, in your computed property, you try to access to gc.produtos that's undefined because gc is still empty. When you get your ajax response, that's asynchronous (so it takes some time to have an actual response), you fill gc and only at this point you can access to gc.produtos. If you want to have gc.produtos the first moment you load your component you have to define it in your data as an empty array like 
 gc: { produtos: [] }

Comment: Could you edit it on codesandbox? I'm having trouble here... because gc is already defined, should I change it or add new? And produtos is defined aswell

Comment: Is it working for you, Davide? Here doesnt happen anything

Comment: It doens't work because your ajax call fails because of CORS as someone other said in one of your posts, but the code is correct

Comment: So how can I fix this CORS stuff?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null"` problem, better to add line before return

```
computed: {
filteredItems() {
  return this.customers.filter(item => {
     return (item.title || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((this.search || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
  })
}}
```

`(this.search || '')` will do trick..